# problem in using module.function in Python

Tags: python, module

I am working on Anaconda Navigator and Jupyter notepad for typing the program
I understood .ipynb becomes a python program and for module I rename it as .py
After renaming I understood it becomes a module object and then I can access functions of that module as attribute.

Then importing that module is working but it is not recognizing the functions in that modules as attributes
Earlier it also say null error I changed null to NULL or None both are working (after making into a module, I changed and saved it as .py not in .ipynb)
But accessing functions as module.attribute  is where I am facing problem

Comment: I have a question. Did you just change the format of file from `.ipynb` to `.py`? (ex. `abc.ipynb -> abc.py`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.